# Delay next item in the axWindowsMediaPlayer playlist until the current item has completed playing

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013, playlist, axwindowsmediaplayer

I have used the following code to create and loop my videos in my playlist:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var pl = axWindowsMediaPlayer1.playlistCollection.newPlaylist("plList");
   pl.appendItem(axWindowsMediaPlayer1.newMedia(@"C:\ABC\abc.mp4"));
   pl.appendItem(axWindowsMediaPlayer1.newMedia(@"C:\XYZ\xyz.mp4"));

   axWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentPlaylist = pl;            
   //axWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.setMode("loop", true);            
   axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
}
```

However, I found out that the next item in the playlist plays for 2 seconds before the end of current item in the playlist. Then, the new item plays all over again (i.e. the first 2 seconds of the item plays twice, once before the end of current item and once at the beginning of the next item).

How do I ensure that the next item is loaded only after the current item is complete playing?

**Requirement 2:** How do I detect the end of Playlist (i.e. After playing of all videos)

I tried to capture it in **PlayStateChange** Event, but I am unable to capture it in either in **Media Ended** or **Stopped** or **Last** states

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perfectly loop your videos, use the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern Boolean GetLastInputInfo(ref tagLASTINPUTINFO plii);
        public struct tagLASTINPUTINFO
        {
            public uint cbSize;
            public Int32 dwTime;
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer1.Start();
        }        

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlenabled = true;
            var pl = axWindowsMediaPlayer1.playlistCollection.newPlaylist("XYZ");
            p1.appendItem(axWindowsMediaPlayer1.newMedia(@"C:\Folder\file1.mp4"));
            pl.appendItem(axWindowsMediaPlayer1.newMedia(@"C:\Folder\file2.mp4"));
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentPlaylist = pl;
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
        }            

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tagLASTINPUTINFO LastInput = new tagLASTINPUTINFO();
            Int32 IdleTime;
            LastInput.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(LastInput);
            LastInput.dwTime = 0;

            if (GetLastInputInfo(ref LastInput))
            {
                IdleTime = System.Environment.TickCount - LastInput.dwTime;
                if (IdleTime > 10000)
                {
                    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.pause();
                    timer1.Stop();
                    MessageBox.Show("Do you wish to continue?");
                }
                timer1.Start();
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
            }
        }
    }
}
```